# Struts2.3.15 freemarker integration

Tags: struts2, freemarker

When I use Struts 2.1.8, I used freemarker like this :

configure a bean in applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="freemarkerManager" 
      class="org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager"/>
```

in the code :

```
try {
    ServletContext servletContext = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
    System.out.println(freemarkerManager.getConfig());
    Configuration configuration = 
                              freemarkerManager.getConfiguration(servletContext);
    Template template = configuration.getTemplate(templateFilePath);
    File htmlFile = new File(servletContext.getRealPath(htmlFilePath));
    File htmlDirectory = htmlFile.getParentFile();
    if (!htmlDirectory.exists()) {
        htmlDirectory.mkdirs();
    }
    Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                                      new FileOutputStream(htmlFile), "UTF-8"));
    template.process(data, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It worked well with Struts 2.1.8;

but now that I use Struts 2.3.15, it doesn't work; it could't load `freemarker.properties`. I read the source code , the problem is the `fileManager` is null in `loadSettings()` method :

```
try {
    in = fileManager.loadFile(
               ClassLoaderUtil.getResource("freemarker.properties", getClass()));
```

in Struts 2.1.8 `loadSettings()` method is like this:

```
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = FileManager.loadFile("freemarker.properties", FreemarkerManager.class);
```

It has no problem

could any one tell me how can I use `freemarkerManager` with Struts 2.3.15?

Comment: Do you actually need FreeMarker configuration from `freemarkerManager` or it is fine if you will create new configuration for it?

Comment: Aleksandr M, you are right, it isn't must get configuration from freemarkerManager, why I use it, first, because Struts2.1.8 work well, I want find why Struts22.3.15 can't work; second, I have a freemarker.properties，I didn't want't set properties myself, so i want FreemarkerManager do it.

Comment: I extend the FreemarkerManager and overrid the loadSettings method like this:public class CustomFreemarkerManager extends FreemarkerManager {
 
 private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomFreemarkerManager.class);

 @Override
  protected void loadSettings(ServletContext servletContext) {
        InputStream in = null;

        try {

         // 获取Freemarker配置文件
         Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("freemarker.properties");
         in = resource.getInputStream();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must initialize `freemarkerManager` like this:

```
FreemarkerManager freemarkerManager = Dispatcher.getInstance().getContainer().getInstance(FreemarkerManager.class);
```